# Python http server how automatically connect from localhost on startup

Tags: python, http.server

The following python script runs on a Pi zero with camera. If I connect from a client with webbrowser the "while True" loop in the streaminhandler prints a message when motion is detected.

I don't always connect from a client but I want the loop started (as if a client connects) upon booting the Pi which starts the script.

How can I make the http server "connect to itself"? I tried the "request" line in the "try" block but that doesn't work, it never gets executed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cv2
import http.server
import socketserver
import requests
import time
import subprocess

def camera():
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video0")
    if not camera.isOpened():
        print("Cannot open camera.")
        raise SystemExit
    camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
    camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)
    camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 15)
    return camera

def process(frame1, frame2):
    framediff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    framegray = cv2.cvtColor(framediff,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frameblur = cv2.GaussianBlur(framegray,(5,5),0)
    threshold = cv2.threshold(frameblur,20,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    dilated   = cv2.dilate(threshold,None,iterations=10)
    contours  = cv2.findContours(dilated,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
    motion = False
    for contour in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 10000:
            continue
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame2,(x, y),(x+w, y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        motion = True
    return frame2, motion
    #return cv2.flip(frame2, -1)

def webpage():
    return """<html><body>
    <img src="stream.mjpg" width="640" height="480" />
    </body></html>"""

class streaminghandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/index.html":
            content = webpage().encode("utf-8")
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/html")
            self.send_header("Content-Length", len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == "/stream.mjpg":
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary")
            self.end_headers()
            while True:
                frame1 = camera.read()[1]
                frame2 = camera.read()[1]
                frame, motion = process(frame1, frame2)
                if motion:
                    print("Motion detected.. " + time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time())))
                frame = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)[1]
                time.sleep(frameinterval)
                self.send_header("Content-type", "image/jpeg")
                self.send_header("Content-length", len(frame))
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(frame)
                self.wfile.write(b"\r\n--jpgboundary\r\n")
        elif self.path == "/image.jpg":
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary")
            self.end_headers
            frame1 = camera.read()[1]
            frame2 = camera.read()[1]
            frame, motion = process(frame1, frame2)
            frame = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)[1]
            self.send_header("Content-type", "image/jpeg")
            self.send_header("Content-length", len(frame))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(frame)
            self.wfile.write(b"\r\n--jpgboundary\r\n")

class streamingserver(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, http.server.HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

try:
    camera = camera()
    frameinterval = 1 / camera.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    streaming_server = streamingserver(("", 8000), streaminghandler)
    print("server started at port 8000")
    streaming_server.serve_forever()
    r = requests.get("http://localhost:8000/stream.mjpg")

except Exception as error:
    print(error)

finally:
    streaming_server.socket.close()
    camera.release()
```

Comment: `server_forever` is blocking, you can create a timer just before starting to serve, which will call your request in a second or two (should be enough). `threading.Timer(interval=2, function=requests.get, args=("http://localhost:8000/stream.mjpg", ))`. And by the way, if you want to have something always running (`while True`) you can just run it in a thread outside that server...

Comment: Adding t = threading.Timer(interval=2, function=requests.get, args=("http://localhost:8000/stream.mjpg", )) and t.start() before streaming_server = .. is working, thank you.

Comment: How do I mark this answer as accepted?

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, so you can't mark it. But glad I could help :)

Comment: @eagr: after adding the timer, the script runs out of memory after 15-30 minutes. Commenting the timer and connect using remote client does not run out of memory. Any ideas?